# Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _dispose_managed_object during deployment to an iOS device

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, linker-errors

Every time I'm trying to debug my Xamarin.iOS app on a device I'm getting the following error

> MTOUCHTASK: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _dispose_managed_object. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly
> linked in.
>
> MTOUCHTASK: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Deploy/Debug on an emulator works fine.
My build settings are the following:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include all version informations. The easiest way to get exact version information is to use the "Xamarin Studio" menu, "About Xamarin Studio" item, "Show Details" button and copy/paste the version informations (you can use the "Copy Information" button).

Comment: I have the latest version of stable Xamarin Studio: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ngsebczrumf7ui/Screenshot%202015-03-10%2022.46.51.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you pastebin the complete build log as well?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge Hello. I have the same behaviour ,but vice versa. On real device its works,on emulator i'm getting same issue as error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol. Can you see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962939/xamarin-ios-binding-libraries-native-frameworks ! Thanks.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge if i put "Link framework SDK only" for emulator, its works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your LinkWith attribute to:

```
[assembly: LinkWith (..., ForceLoad = false, SmartLink = true)]
```